# Is there an ffmpeg flag to not ask for overwrite but add a number at the end?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a script that converts ~8000 files to mp3. I have some files that have a sielar name, where just the extension is diffrent, and they would create all the same .mp3 file with my script at the moment.

So I just want ffmpeg to add something like (x) at the end of the name befor the extension and not ask me every few files.

Thank you!

Comment: See this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/922866/ffmpeg-skip-process-if-output-already-exists this -n option worked well for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg does not have the functionality you describe.

You need to implement it in your script instead.
Or (on the FFmpeg command line) explicitly specify such output file name that is guaranteed not to exist.
For example, if all your input files are in the same directory, then for an input file named **fname.ext** use output file named **fname.ext.mp3** and place it in a new directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it would be nice if ffmpeg would get something like that in the future, maybe I'll do a feature request.

Answer (score 4):

The flag for overwrite without asking y/n is ( -y  ), just include -y in your command.

(-y overwrites files of same name without asking).

Look at ffmpeg docs: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html. 
To find this flag just search for "overwrite" key word in the docs.

Example to extract an image from video and save it without asking y/n.

```
ffmpeg -i <video_file_here> -y -ss 00:00:00 -vframes 1 image.jpg)
```

Now to save file name with a new number each time you can make a bat file with a loop counter variable and increase the number and issue the command with the new number each time.

for a reference on how to do this, you can check one of my questions here.  [incrementing a counter variable inside a FORLOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137004/incrementing-a-counter-variable-inside-a-forloop)